# PHP/mysql:Get correct year in php 5.3

Tags: php, date, strtotime

My host updated from PHP 5.2 to PHP 5.3 and my date code no longer returns a year such as 2015 but instead a minus sign -1.

```
Wednesday November 30, 2015
```

has become

```
Wednesday November 30, -1
```

This is evidently because the command `date` has changed. Despite trying out a lot of options, I can't get it to display properly

Here is my code that used to work and is now giving a -1 for the year.

```
function fulldatetime($datetime) {
$fullDate = strtotime($datetime);
$fullDate = date("l F jS, o, g:i A",$fullDate);
return $fullDate;
}
```

where $datetime is of the form: `2015-12-28 23:00:00`

Can anyone explain to me the correct code to get the year to display right.

Thanks in advance for helping me to solve this vexing problem.

Comment: Works for me https://3v4l.org/UTdBc

Comment: Tryied on php _5.4.45_ and the output is : `Monday December 28th, 2015, 11:00 PM`. Please check you are actually using a well formatted input in the parameter of your function `fulldatetime`. I would also add that today there is better library to manipulate date like `[DateTime()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)`.

Comment: What is the result of `$fullDate = strtotime($datetime);`?

Comment: Worked for me on `PHP 5.5.15` .

Comment: Works for me w/ PHP 5.3.29.

Answer (score 0):

use 'Y' instead of 'o' ? 
: date("l F jS, Y, g:i A",$fullDate);

via http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative using a not so new date library OOP [**DateTime()**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). Here is the function :

```
<?php
    function fulldatetime($datetime)
    {
        return (new DateTime($datetime))->format("l M d, Y");       
    }

    printf(fulldatetime("2015-12-28 23:00:00"));
?>
```

You can try it using [**Viper-7**](http://viper-7.com/JIrm7T), which is an online website to compile PhP Code.

Format description :

- l : day of the week in full letter
- M : month number in full letter
- d : number of the day of the month
- Y : year in 4 digit format

Comment: The issue arises when the date is 0000-00-00 00:00:00.  I guess I could fix it by never setting the date to that value but it used to work okay.